# ¿Cómo eliminar objetos de un vector de clases con el mismo parámetro?

Tags: c++

Mi problema es que quiero eliminar todos objetos de mi vector que tengan el mismo modelo. El usuario selecciona de la lista uno de los objetos y cuando presiona eliminar modelo seleccionado se eliminaran todos los que tengan el mismo modelo.
Solo me funciona el de eliminar un carro con el siguiente código:

```
    void eliminar(int pos)
        {
            arrCarros.erase(begin(arrCarros) + pos);
        }
```

Donde pos es el selectedindex de el listbox y me funciono. Para eliminar el mismo modelo aplique:

```
    void eliminarModelo(int pos)
    {
        char* x = new char[50];
        x = arrCarros[pos]->getModelo();
        for (int i = 0;i< arrCarros.size(); i++)
        {
            if (arrCarros[i]->getModelo() == x)
            {
                arrCarros.erase(begin(arrCarros) + i);
            }
        }

    }
```

Pero lo único que hace es eliminar el seleccionado y no los que tengan el mismo modelo.

```
CArrCarro.h

#ifndef __CARRCARROS_H__
#define __CARRCARROS_H__
#include <vector>
#include "CCarros.h"
using namespace std;
class CArrCarros
{
public:
    CArrCarros()
    {
    }

    ~CArrCarros()
    {
    }

    void agregar(CCarros* x)
    {
        arrCarros.push_back(x);
    }

    void eliminar(int pos)
    {
        arrCarros.erase(begin(arrCarros) + pos);
    }

    void eliminarModelo(int pos)
    {
        char* x = new char[50];
        x = arrCarros[pos]->getModelo();
        for (int i = 0;i< arrCarros.size(); i++)
        {
            if (arrCarros[i]->getModelo() == x)
            {
                arrCarros.erase(begin(arrCarros) + i);
            }
        }

    }

    vector<CCarros*> getCarros() { return arrCarros; }

private:
    vector<CCarros*> arrCarros;

};



#endif // !__CARRCARROS_H__
```

Este es mi formulario
[image: Formulario]

Comment: Esta eliminarModelo() no se ve nada bien... Primero creas el puntero x para después asignarle lo que devuelva getModelo(). También deberías tener en cuenta que vector::erase reduce el size del vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparte de lo comentado por @Dolmenes...

```
void eliminarModelo(int pos)
{
    char* x = new char[50];
    x = arrCarros[pos]->getModelo();
    for (int i = 0;i< arrCarros.size(); i++)
    {
        if (/* comparacion del modelo */)
        {
            arrCarros.erase(begin(arrCarros) + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Cada vez que se llama a `arrCarros.erase` se elimina un elemento del vector... y todos los siguientes se desplazan una posición... pero esta última circunstancia no la tienes en cuenta, es decir, si tienes el siguiente vector:

```
A A B
```

Sucedería lo siguiente:

- Encuentras A y eliminas el elemento de la posición 0, queda: `A B`
- Compruebas el elemento de la posicion 1, `B`, lo ignoras. El vector final será `A B`

Lo que tienes que hacer es evitar el incremento si sacas un elemento del vector:

```
for (int i = 0;i< arrCarros.size(); i++)
{
    if (/* comparacion del modelo */)
    {
        arrCarros.erase(begin(arrCarros) + i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bien visto. Se me pasó :-)

Comment: @Dolmenes en otras ocasiones sucede al revés :)

Answer (score 2):

Fíjate bien en lo que haces:

```
void eliminarModelo( int pos ) {
  char* x = new char[50];
  x = arrCarros[pos]->getModelo( );
```

Creas un arreglo en memoria dinámica, pero **le asignas el valor devuelto por `getModelo( )`**.

Ya vamos mal. De momento, tienes pérdidas de memoria. Seguimos.

```
  for (int i = 0;i< arrCarros.size(); i++) {
    if (arrCarros[i]->getModelo() == x) {
```

Vamos empeorando. Comparamos `x` con el valor devuelto por `getModelo( )`. Eso fué precisamente lo que hicimos al obtener el primer valor de `x`. Y dicha variable es un *puntero*; es decir, esa comparación **solo nos dará `true` para el índice `pos`**.

Cualquier otra comparación, nos dará siempre `false`.

Una posible solución sería:

```
#include <string.h>

. . .

void eliminarModelo( int pos ) {
  char* x = new char[50];

  strcpy( x, arrCarros[pos]->getModelo( ) );

  for( int i = 0;i< arrCarros.size(); i++ )
    if( !strcmp( arrCarros[i]->getModelo( ), x ) )
      arrCarros.erase(begin(arrCarros) + i);

  delete[] x;
}
```

Esa solución depende de varias cosas. Principalmente, que tu función `getModelo( )` devuelva un puntero a una cadena **terminada en 0** y de tamaño `<= 49` caracteres (necesitamos 1 para el `0` final).

Comment: Funciono, pero le falto el  i--; de @eferion. Todavía estoy aprendiendo a programar y me espera un largo camino. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @JuanDiegoRomeroPeralta cierto, se me pasó por completo :-)

Comment: ¿`<string.h>`? O_o

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster si si, el *header* de _C_. Tal y como está el código, es lo suyo. Tendría que haber usado `std::string` ... pues si, pero es que me salió así :-)

Comment: En `eliminarModelo` ni siquiera hace falta copiar el retorno de `arrCarros[pos]->getModelo()`, dado que va a ser usado por `strcmp` y esta función no modifica los datos que se le facilitan, perfectamente `x` podría asignarse al retorno de `arrCarros[pos]->getModelo()` sin consecuencias negativas y nos ahorramos el `new`, el `strcpy` y el `delete[]`.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Absolutamente cierto. Nada, que me vas a hacer borrar la respuesta, por mala :-/

Comment: La respuesta es muy buena, pero mejorable. No borres nada, edita :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la cabecera de algoritmos ([`<algorithm>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)), en concreto la función para eliminar elementos de colecciones [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

```
void eliminarModelo(int pos)
{
    const auto &x = arrCarros[pos]->getModelo();
    auto i = std::remove_if(arrCarros.begin(), arrCarros.end(),
    [&x](auto carro){ return std::strcmp(carro->getModelo(), x) == 0; });

    for (auto b = i, e = arrCarros.end(); b != e; ++b)
        delete *b;

    arrCarros.erase(i, arrCarros.end());
}
```

La función `std::remove_if` recibe dos parámetros de rango (inicio y final de la colección en que borrar) y un tercer parámetro que sería una función (llamada [predicado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicado_(l%C3%B3gica)#Sem.C3.A1ntica_formal)) que debe devolver verdadero si el elemento ha de ser borrado.

La función `std::remove_if` en realidad no borra los elementos que cumplen con el predicado si no que los mueve al final de la colección y devuelve un iterador a lo que debería ser el nuevo final<sup>1</sup> de la colección.

Dado que has usado memoria dinámica para alojar las instancias de `CCarros`, no se puede hacer el borrado directo sin provocar [fugas de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria), así que es necesario un bucle adicional para aplicar `delete` sobre los elementos antes de llamar a `std::vector::erase`.

Sin embargo, si cambias el tipo de `arrCarros` a `std::vector<CCarros>` la función `eliminarModelo` puede quedar como:

```
void eliminarModelo(int pos)
{
    const auto &x = arrCarros[pos].getModelo();
    auto i = std::remove_if(arrCarros.begin(), arrCarros.end(),
    [&x](auto carro){ return std::strcmp(carro.getModelo(), x) == 0; });

    arrCarros.erase(i, arrCarros.end());
}
```

Pero para que eso sea posible, la clase `CCarros` debe cumplir con el concepto Móvil-Asignable ([`MoveAssignable`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable)).

#### A tener en cuenta.

1. **Memoria**: [Dolmenes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/75884/2742) ya ha hablado de las fugas de memoria, pero yo insistiré aún más en ello. Para evitar las fugas de memoria debes usar [punteros inteligentes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puntero_inteligente) o no usar punteros en absoluto, mi consejo es que no uses punteros a no ser que sea estrictamente necesario (y en tu caso no parece serlo), así te ahorras los `new` y `delete` además de no necesitar trabajo adicional en el destructor de `CArrCarros` (que ahora necesitas y no has puesto).
2. **Estilo**: Los nombres usados para tus clases son confusos, no tengo nada en contra de la [Notación Húngara](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notaci%C3%B3n_h%C3%BAngara) para identificar clases, pero usar el plural para objetos que conceptualmente son únicos es confuso, cambia `CCarros` por `CCarro`.
3. **Seguridad**: Devuelves una copia de tus datos internos en la función `getCarros`, esto no es malo *per se* aunque si ineficiente. Como devuelves una copia de un `std::vector` de punteros, estás dando acceso total a los elementos almacenados en `CArrCarros` rompiendo su [encapsulación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)) y permitiendo que procesos ajenos modifiquen (¡o borren!) el estado interno de la clase sin que esta tenga control sobre esos cambios. Este problema lo solucionas aplicando el consejo 1 y devolviendo el `std::vector` como constante, puedes evitar la copia si lo devuelves como referencia constante.

---

<sup>1</sup>En C++, los finales de las colecciones son un iterador al elemento posterior al último elemento de la colección.